# Does an application developed on HTTP/1.x require modifications to run on HTTP/2?

Tags: http2

In the [HTTP/2 chapter in the High Performance Browser Networking book](https://hpbn.co/http2/), there is a mention that

> all existing applications can be delivered without modification.

Existing application using HTTP/1.1 use a request line, like `POST /upload HTTP/1.1`.

I think some code in our application should instead move the request line to a header frame. That means our application should consider the change from request line to header frame and deal with data frames as well.

Isn't that a modification?

Comment: Most applications don't handle HTTP themselves, instead they use other libs to send request/receive response. And since the semantics didn't change, that's why *all existing applications can be delivered without modification.*

Answer (score 3):

This assumes your application is abstracted away from the raw HTTP implementation - as most applications are.

For example, let's assume you have created a Javascript web application (e.g. Angular), that talks through REST APIs to a web server (e.g. Apache), which proxies requests to a backend server (e.g. Node.js).

By adding HTTP/2 to the Apache Webserver your website and web application should benefit from HTTP/2 and be downloaded faster without **any** changes to your code. This despite the fact that your application (at both the front end Angular app and the back end Node.js server) likely uses a lot of HTTP semantics (e.g. Methods like GET and POST, headers... etc.). The web browser and web server should handle all the HTTP/2 stuff for you with no requirement to change your code or realise that you are using a different version of HTTP than what you originally write this app for as, fundamentally the concepts of HTTP have not changed even if the delivery method on the wire has.

Of course if you are writing at a lower level, and directly reading the bytes from the HTTP request then this may not be the case. But in most cases, unless you are writing a web server or browser, you will be going through a library and not looking at the direct request line and/or HTTP/2 frames.

Additionally, as the author of that book states above and below this quote, while changes will not be necessary in most cases to keep the application functioning, to get the **most** out of HTTP/2 may require changes to stop using HTTP/1.1 optimisations and learn new HTTP/2 optimisations.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on BazzaDP's answer, from an application standpoint running on a web application framework, nothing changes. Those frameworks provide an abstraction of the underlying HTTP innards.

For example ASP.NET running on IIS provides a `Request` and `Response` object to the developer.

You can still use those objects' properties like `Request.Headers` or `Response.Body`, even though in HTTP/2 jargon those are called and transported different from HTTP/1.x.

The web server itself or the application framework running on top of it will handle the translation from network traffic to that object's properties and vice versa.